# Custom Domain pointing to heroku app changes URL in browser?

Tags: heroku

I have an website hosted on heroku. App url is like **example.herokuapp.com**

I bought domain with name **www.example.com** and on visiting this URL I pointed to **example.herokuapp.com**. This works fine however URL in browser changes to heroku app rather it should stay custom domain **www.example.com**

What configurations are required?

Answer (score 1):

That suggests you're using domain forwarding at your DNS provider and not adding a CNAME entry to your domain pointing at `example.herokuapp.com` for the www host

Comment: i added CNAME as you told but it works only for example.com and not www.example.com

Without "www" it works fine but with "www" it again shows url of heroku app name.

Is there way to redirect www.example to example.com so it will work..?

Comment: If you're DNS provider supports redirects then you can do it there else you need to do the redirect at your application layer.